# How to monitor FTE agent status

Tags: websphere-mq-fte

I want to monitor FTE agent's status, if fte agent is down or unavailable then i want to send email or some kind of alert saying agent is down. Pleas help

Answer (score 0):

Use any convenient monitor program to check the input handle status on the agent's command queue.  If there's no input handle, the agent is down.  If the queue has an input handle and you want to know if the agent is responsive, you can either watch for periodic status updates on the agent's topic, or send it a status inquiry message.